# Galleriffic: get the current and absolute Image Number

Tags: image, gallery, image-gallery

i try something like this: `var test = gallery.currentImage.index;`
but nothing works.

Comment: i'm Having the same problem...  i cant figure out how to show the current number and the total

Comment: try this:
variablename = gallery.currentImage.index (for the current)
variablename = gallery.data.length-1; (for the last/total)

i hope it will work

Answer (score 1):

I found this easy way to  Show the Current and Absolute image number. You can follow this exemple.

http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/example-5.html

Answer (score 0):

I've been using nextIndex which I believe is an array that starts at 0. For example you can trigger something with "onSlideChange" as follows:

```
onSlideChange: function(prevIndex, nextIndex) {
var idx = nextIndex + 1;
if(idx==2)
alert('hello world!);
}
```